# How to download hotlink protected images?

Tags: java, image, hotlinking

I want to download images from other websites that are hotlink protected. I don't want to link those images to my website. I just wanted to download them.

Comment: With Java? Just do the normal `url.openConnection` dance. As long as you don't pass in a `Referer` header, you should get the image.

Comment: (To clarify, most hotlink protection allows connections with no `Referer` at all, since they are optional in HTTP and may well not be present; they only block present `Referer`​s pointing to a third-party site. There are some blockers that *require* the first-party site to be present in the `Referer` (in which case you'd have to add it manually), but since this has many undesirable side-effects for the site it should be quite rare.)

Comment: Can someone reopen the question so I can answer it?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [usual hotlink-protection method](http://www.albionresearch.com/disaster/sex_sells.php) checks if the ["Referrer" HTTP Header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer) matches the domain name of the original website.

You can easily bypass that by setting that header manually to point to a page in the website.

Answer (score 11):

You need to pass the referrer http header. You can do this with wget on most unix systems as follows:

```
wget --referer=http://www.google.com/ http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif
```

Here a raw way to do it so you see exactly what is going on:

```
telnet google.com 80
GET /intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif HTTP/1.1
REFERER: http://www.google.com/
HOST: www.google.com
```

Answer (score 5):

You can download hotlink protected images by using the following code:

```
URL url = new URL("http://www.somesite.com/picture.jpg");

URLConnection urlCon = url.openConnection();
urlConn.setRequestProperty("Referer", "http://www.somesite.com");
urlConn.connect();

InputStream urlStream = urlCon.getInputStream();

Image image = ImageIO.read(urlStream);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Postman extension for Chrome lets you make custom http requests. I found a hotlink-blocked image, copied it's url and entered it into Postman to GET it.

Comment: I used the following Postman extension, put the image URL in and only works when hotlinking is not enabled. Are there kinds of hotlinking that disable this? https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/menjpgnehajklienmnkhflpmkncmnfno/related